# How to parse error with Square Connect API example (Node)

Tags: javascript, node.js, square, square-connect

I am trying to learn how to process payments with Square, and am trying to run their examples from GitHub to get a feel regarding how to structure the payments application.  I built the node example from here: https://github.com/square/connect-api-examples/tree/master/connect-examples/v2/node_payment using `npm install` and `npm build` to get the app up and running.

I am using "4532759734545858" for the card number, "123" for CVV, "0120" for expiration, and "94103" for the zip.  I got the card number from here: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/using-sandbox where it states that this is a good number to use for a Visa sandbox.

Also, I have updated the `config.json` with properties from my developer settings.

When trying to process a payment a get a DOM element that says "Card Declined" without further specifying the error.  Is there something I can do to parse the error?

Based on the documentation at: https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/using-sandbox#generatingerrorstates it seems the `amount_money` field of the request is not being populated, but I am having trouble confirming.

Ideally I would like to get to a point where I can add a card as a hash value to my db and use it for recurring billing...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That "card declined" message is actually the error you get back from Square's APIs. You can play around with the error messaging in the `app.js` file and the `error.jade. Try error.catagory, code, detail.

Keep in mind that this is just a sample app, to show that you can use the APIs with node.js, you probably don't want to use this code in your production system.

Comment: Yes, I am just working out your examples, because I am having trouble handling the nonce and making a payment.  I am a bit confused as to how to store a card on file and charge the stored card.  I have successfully been able to create and update a customer using Node and Unirest on the server.

Comment: I am not familiar with Jade, but I added ```h2=error.category``` to the ```error.jade``` file and it displays the same info in the DOM.

Comment: I restarted the server with ```npm start``` and it works now.  ¯\_(ツ)_/¯